# Help understand this PHP code download file

Tags: php, file, download

I want to download a doc file located at http://confluence.rogersdigitalmedia.com/exportword?pageId=1114407. How can I modify the following code to download a file from that URL??

And can someone please explain what this code does in its current state, what does it download, a file from a directory?

```
<?php

// place this code inside a php file and call it f.e. "download.php"
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path2file/"; // change the path to fit your websites document structure
$fullPath = $path.$_GET['download_file'];

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
        header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
        break;
        default;
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    }
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;
// example: place this kind of link into the document where the file download is offered:
// <a href="download.php?download_file=some_file.pdf">Download here</a>
?>
```

Comment: That looks overly complicated to me. Why not use file_get_contents()?

Comment: The code there does more than just opening a file. It also offers the entire file to the browser for download.

Comment: Eww.... [Path traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_traversal) alert!

Comment: @Ash: Because file_get_contents will slurp up the entire file into PHP memory. large files will probably exceed PHP's `memory_limit` and kill the script. However, doing an `fread()` loop like that is just excess code, when `readfile()` does that all for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This code is supposed to download files through PHP. Usually, it's used to hide the directory containing the downloads, or to download files which were otherwise inaccessible because the files are outside the web root. Another use for such a script is to offer downloads for authorized users, you'd have to put an authentication check in the script.

If the file has a PDF extension, the download is offered as with the PDF mimetype, so browsers can open it in a PDF viewer. Other files are offered as binary files which can be saved.

Do not use this script "as-is". It contains a huge security vulnerability which allows an attacker to view arbitrary files on your system ([Path traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_traversal)). Replace line:

```
$fullPath = $path.$_GET['download_file'];
```

with the following to make it a bit more secure:

```
$fullPath = $path . basename($_GET['download_file']);
```

Even better: implement whitelisting by allowing filenames within an allowed character set and rejecting other invalid filenames.

---

Downloading an external file is as easy as following the [example of cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php):

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Since I've no clue about the URL of your download, I'll leave the original URLs and filenames from the PHP example.

Comment: thanks for the help but I dont want to use this file.....if possible Id liek to use wget but how do I execute wget.exe or use wget in my web host? Im using Cygwin on my computer to execute wget but if I want to run wget on my web host and download the file into my web host how do I do that?

Comment: That `/exportword` page shows me a 403 Forbidden message. What do you exactly want? Download a file from that server to your own one?

Comment: Re: wget. This answer describes exactly what the file you supplied does. It sounds like you are trying to do something entirely different, so please ask your actual question in future. The script you copied presents a file for download to users browsing your site. If you want to download a file to the server, use `file_get_contents` if your host lets you set `allow_url_fopen`, or follow the example in the `curl_init` documentation page.

Comment: What I am trying to do is download a doc file from a url using php and put it in my webhost.....I CANNOT DOWNLOAD ANY FRAMEWORKS OR LIBRARIES BECAUSE MY COMPANY DOESNT ALLOW ME.

Comment: @user761669: no need for shouting, if your host supports cURL, you can use the example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code is something you put on your own server to allow people to download files *through* PHP.  Usually you'd add some authentication code in there so PHP can accept/reject the user before downloading.

Comment: how can I write a php code to download a doc file from a url to a directory in my webhost?