# how do I use this remote download file in PHP?

Tags: php, function, download

It took me FOREVER to finally find code that can download a doc file using php from a URL...

But I am experimenting and can't figure out what I am doing wrong to make it work...help..
My webhost only I can access is at http://dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com

I would like it for the time being to download a file from dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com/Team+Calendar.doc and put it back into my web hosts different directory which is called "testing"
I tried different parameters but dont know what I am doing wrong please help, I am so confused and frustrated what do I need to do here...

```
<?php

/* Function: download remote file */
/* Parameters: $url -> to download | $dir -> where to store file |
    $file_name -> store file as this name - if null, use default*/


function downloadRemoteFile($url,$dir,$file_name = NULL){
    if($file_name == NULL){ $file_name = basename($url);}
    $url_stuff = parse_url($url);
    $port = isset($url_stuff['port']) ? $url_stuff['port'] : 80;

    $fp = fsockopen($url_stuff['host'], $port);
    if(!$fp){ return false;}

    $query  = 'GET ' . $url_stuff['path'] . " HTTP/1.0\n";
    $query .= 'Host: ' . $url_stuff['host'];
    $query .= "\n\n";

    fwrite($fp, $query);

    while ($tmp = fread($fp, 8192))   {
        $buffer .= $tmp;
    }

    preg_match('/Content-Length: ([0-9]+)/', $buffer, $parts);
    $file_binary = substr($buffer, - $parts[1]);
    if($file_name == NULL){
        $temp = explode(".",$url);
        $file_name = $temp[count($temp)-1];
    }
    $file_open = fopen($dir . "/" . $file_name,'w');
    if(!$file_open){ return false;}
    fwrite($file_open,$file_binary);
    fclose($file_open);
    return true;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Use `file_get_contents('http://dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com/Team+Calendar.doc');` or http://php.net/curl

Comment: Please pay attention and stop asking the same question over and over. You can download a file in PHP wit a **single function call**: `file_get_contents`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help understand this PHP code download file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228750/help-understand-this-php-code-download-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all the code you need with the function:

```
$url = "http://dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com/Team+Calendar.doc";
$dir = "testing";
downloadRemoteFile($url,$dir);
```

Also the target directory (`$dir`) should be writeable. And your webserver must allow outbound HTTP connections.

Comment: thanks a bunch bud for actually answering the question and helping

Answer (score 0):

you will need to have allow url fopen allowed in your php.ini contact your webhost for this after that you can do

```
$fp = fopen( $url );
$data = fread( $fp, 204800) // 2 mb
```

and write $data to a destination file using fwrite that should do it

other wise you can also use

```
file_get_contents and file_put_contents
```